# Capture response stream and output to file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

We are using an online pdf encoding service where we send them the raw html and they return the pdf document.  We want to take the WebResponse and immediately download it as a file to their desktop.  This seems so straightforward and yet I can't seem to capture the stream correctly for download.  I've tried many different approaches but I always end up with a 0 byte file for download.  This is my latest incarnation which has gotten overly complicated but it still doesn't work.

```
 Dim request = DirectCast(HttpWebRequest.Create(Url), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Method = "POST"
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Using dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    End Using

    Try
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse
        Dim bytes As Byte()
        Using st As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            Dim ByteList As New ArrayList
            Dim reader As New BinaryReader(st)
            Dim length As Integer

            While (InlineAssignHelper(bytes, reader.ReadBytes(1024))).Length > 0
                ByteList.Add(bytes)
                length += bytes.Length
                bytes = New Byte(length - 1) {}
                Dim position As Integer = 0
                For Each b As Byte() In ByteList
                    Array.Copy(b, 0, bytes, position, b.Length)
                    position += b.Length
                Next
            End While
        End Using
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf")
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename=Report Detail.pdf; size={1}", "attachment", bytes.Length.ToString()))
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close()
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
 Private Shared Function InlineAssignHelper(Of T)(ByRef target As T, ByVal value As T) As T
    target = value
    Return value
End Function
```

Comment: The code in [How do I download a webpage into a stream in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/929823/1115360) should be fairly easy to convert from C# to VB. Please note that a BinaryReader does not do what its name suggests; it "Reads primitive data types as binary values in a specific encoding."

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  I had searched and came up with nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I download a webpage into a stream in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/929808/how-do-i-download-a-webpage-into-a-stream-in-net)